# Google map - places wont show right address

Tags: google-maps-api-3, autocomplete, google-places-api, autosuggest

Here I have a code with autosuggestion places via google places API but when I type etc. "paris, france" it wont show on map, why?

Does anyone have similar probem?

here is demo:
http://jsbin.com/ayugun/57

here is code:
http://jsbin.com/ayugun/57/edit

Comment: when I type "paris, france, bars" all works fine but "paris, france" and similar don't work, - wont show on map

Answer (score 0):

I'm not able to point out the mistake, yet I can show an similar working example in [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dodger/pbbhH/) using `google maps v3` and autocomplete.

Comment: This is not what I need. I just want to know why my code wont show map on place I type